# Why is the following an example of a mutative accumulation operation?

Tags: java, java-8

According to [Java docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#Reduction), the following is a mutative accumulation operation. Can someone please explain what a mutative accumulation operation is and how does it apply to the following piece of code?

```
int sum = 0;
for (int x : numbers) {
  sum += x;
}
```

Comment: You can read about [Mutation of  Java Objects](https://www.cs.colostate.edu/~bieman/Pubs/AlexanderBiemanGhoshJiISSRE02.pdf)

Answer (score 4):

The standard dictionary definitions for each of those words in the term should get you most of the way to understanding.

It's *mutative* because it mutates (changes/alters/ etc) the variable `sum` to arrive at the result

It's an *accumulation* because the numbers are added to form the sum gradually